# HTML - How to open an a href that leads to a div

Tags: html

So I have two separate HTML files. The first one holds a section with id="portfolio". The second one holds an a href. When I click the a href in the second HTML file I want to go to the first HTML file at the #porfolio section position. I know how to open the first HTML file from the a href. I also know how to get to the #porfolio section from the first HTML file. What I don't know is how can get to the #portfolio section in the first HTML file through the second HTML file. So how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

First HTML:

```
<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
...
</section>
```

Second HTML:

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
```

Comment: you can use this plugin for hash events http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work when included in second.html:
    `<a class="page-scroll" href="first.html#portfolio">Portfolio</a>`

Comment: Worked as expected. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: you have 2 pages open in a webbrowser (the same webbrowser) and you want to jump back and forth between the 2 different pages, causing the web browser to change tabs/windows and re-display the requested page(s) at the anchor point you specify.

You need to talk to webbrowser and get it to do the work for you. The answer is browser specific.

I would start by creating child page (target='_blank') of original page and seeing what individual browsers allow you to get away with. Your mileage may vary, as they say.